# How to get a calendar (google calendar or exchange) with .netcore

Tags: .net-core, exchange-server

I want to write a service that gets calendars from external sources (exchange or google calendars)
The service is used for a project to improve room occupancy.

So how do i start? Any advice or links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find two links about consuming Google Calendar or Exchange web services, using .NET technologies. Both contain code samples.

[Google Calendar .NET API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)

[Exchange Web Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange)